# StructureMap & Lazy Initialization via Constructor with Interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, lazy-loading, structuremap

I use StructureMap v4.6.1.0 and I have a structure where I create an instance using the constructor into which I insert an interface of that class, and this class usually invokes my constructor that has its parameters in its service which they use

```
 private readonly IFirstService _firstService;
 private readonly ISecondService _secondService;

 private readonly ILog _log;

 public ProductController(IFirstService firstService, ISecondService secondService, ILog log)
 {
       _firstService = firstService;
       _secondService = secondService;

       _log = log;
 }

 [Route("Default")]
 public ActionResult First()
 {
       var model = _firstService.DoIt();
       return View("~/Views/First/index.cshtml", model);
 }

 [Route("Default")]
 public ActionResult Second()
 {
       var model = _secondService.DoIt();
       return View("~/Views/Second/index.cshtml", model);
 }
```

Main problem of this solution is then I call Controller then it makes a 2 instances (one for firstService and second for secondService), but this services I call for specific controller page method.

For example, service call in constructor interface for the factory, log and repository loader, thas mean when I call controller constructor I load all repositories from both services-

- Can I use C#.NET Lazy(T) or Func?
- Can I use interface as a parameter in the method for the selected page?
- Can I use Cache for read-only data from the repository?
- Another solution?

When I use Lazy I got the message then called procedure is not defined

I am looking for best architecture solution, I try some Lazy and also code optimalization, but I have always encountered a problem

**Edit:**

StructureMap Container Registration

```
Scan(
    scan =>
    {
           scan.TheCallingAssembly();
           scan.WithDefaultConventions();
           scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
    });

For<ILog>().Use(c => LogManager.GetLogger(GetType())).Singleton();

For<IFirstService>().Use<FirstService>().Singleton();
For<ISecondService>().Use<SecondService>().Singleton();
```

**My Solution:**

- Can I use interface as parameter in method for the selected page?

In class constructor I use interface of StructureMap

```
private readonly IContainer _container;
private readonly ILog _log;

public ProductController(IContainer container, ILog log)
{
       _container = container;
       _log = log;
}
```

And in the method I use

```
var model = _container.GetInstance<IFirstService>().DoIt();
```

- Can I use Cache for read-only data from the repository?

I use .NET lib *using static System.Web.HttpRuntime;* and use code below in method called in the constructor of the repository class

```
if (!(Cache[_cacheName] is IEnumerable<YourObject> result)) // Cache is empty
            {
                _log.Info("-- Loading from DB --");
                lock (CacheLockObject)
                {
                    result = Cache[_cacheName] as IEnumerable<YourObject>;
                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        result = LoadAll(); // load data from DB
                        Cache.Insert(_cacheName, result, null,
                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), TimeSpan.Zero);
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }

            _log.Info("-- Loading from Cache --");
            return result;
```

Thank you

Comment: From your question it is not very clear what you want to achieve. Could you post the structure map class where you are registering all dependencies. Also if you want to share same repository instances in a request look at context scoped lifecycle like in this answer  [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489800/structuremap-and-http-request-scoped-services-why-is-my-service-created-twice)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I've already found the solution I've been looking for, please see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current solution for dependency injection is using service locator anti-pattern. The container should not be passed around as a dependency. Doing so is a clear indicator of service locator.

You can defer the initialization by either using `Lazy<T>` or `Func<T>`

For example the following uses `Func<T>`

```
private readonly Func<IFirstService> _firstService;
private readonly Func<ISecondService> _secondService;    
private readonly ILog _log;

public ProductController(Func<IFirstService> firstService, Func<ISecondService> secondService, ILog log) {
    _firstService = firstService;
    _secondService = secondService;    
    _log = log;
 }

[Route("Default")]
public ActionResult First() {
    IFirstService service = _firstService();//invoke delegate to get service
    var model = service.DoIt();
    return View("~/Views/First/index.cshtml", model);
}

[Route("Default")]
public ActionResult Second() {
    ISecondService service = _secondService();
    var model = service.DoIt();
    return View("~/Views/Second/index.cshtml", model);
}
```

The `Func` act as factory delegates which delays the initialization/activation of the dependencies only when they are needed.

So in the above example, if `First()` is requested then only the `_firstService()` delegate is invoked for that request and not both services.

You can do the same with `Lazy<T>`

```
private readonly Lazy<IFirstService> _firstService;
private readonly Lazy<ISecondService> _secondService;    
private readonly ILog _log;

public ProductController(Lazy<IFirstService> firstService, Lazy<ISecondService> secondService, ILog log) {
    _firstService = firstService;
    _secondService = secondService;    
    _log = log;
 }

[Route("Default")]
public ActionResult First() {
    IFirstService service = _firstService.Value;//lazy load service
    var model = service.DoIt();
    return View("~/Views/First/index.cshtml", model);
}

[Route("Default")]
public ActionResult Second() {
    ISecondService service = _secondService.Value;
    var model = service.DoIt();        
    return View("~/Views/Second/index.cshtml", model);
}
```

[StructureMap Documentation: Lazy Resolution](https://structuremap.github.io/the-container/lazy-resolution/)

> StructureMap has some built in functionality for "lazy" resolved dependencies, so that instead of your application service taking a direct dependency on `IExpensiveToBuildService` that might not be necessary, you could instead have StructureMap fulfill a dependency on `Lazy<IExpensiveToBuildService>` or `Func<IExpensiveToBuildService>` that could be used to retrieve that expensive service only when it is needed from whatever Container originally created the parent object.

Comment: When I use Lazy<T> or Func<T> I got, when I call method of service this error:

`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Func<IFirstService>' does not contain a definition for 'DoIt' and no accessible extension method 'DoIt' accepting a first argument of type 'Func<IFirstService>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @JanSršeň you have to invoke the function. look at how I make the call in the action ` _firstService()`. note the brackets. Then you can call your members of the activated object, Look at the examples from the documentation as well.

Comment: @JanSršeň I've rewritten it to give you a better understanding of how to use them

Comment: Now it works I only miss the brackets, I rewrite It and check functionality, Is there any difference between Lazy and Func? Or which is recommended to use?

Comment: @JanSršeň Func is just a delegate, while Lazy is a class that uses a Func delegate which is invoked when you call the `Lazy.Value` property. The Func was the original way the framework did it. Lazy was added later. Both work and it is just a matter of your preference which one you want to use. `Lazy` would be the easier more intuitive one to use.

Comment: Mkosi - Thank you for your help